# $r Apache request in CGI?

Tags: apache, perl, cgi

In trying to find a solution for another question ([passing variables in cgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25627164/figure-out-apache-mod-rewrite-resolutions-in-perl-cgi-and-passing-variable-value)) I ran into the concept of `apache_notes` which then led me to a series of modules on CPAN that use the mysterious `$r`variable (both of which I have run into before while looking other stuff up, but did not delve too deeply into). None of the modules really explain where `$r` comes from, they just all assume you have it readily available. From what I can understand the variable has something to do with `mod_perl` (which I also know little to nothing about) and/or apache `handlers`.

So my question is, is there a way to get that `$r` apache request variable in CGI script calls, without the use of `mod_perl` or apache `handler` definitions?

Also, if there is a way to access `apache_notes` in CGI, I think that would answer the aforementioned question, and an answer there for how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!)

Answer (score 2):

No. It's the Apache (libapr) request object. If you're not embedded in Apache, there's no Apache request object.

But there's no use for notes in a CGI anyway; there isn't any other piece of code that the script could be sharing information with by hanging it off of the request object, so you can just use a variable instead.

Comment: my use for notes would be to call another script (ideally it would be an apache subrequest, but I don't think that's possible outside of mod_perl or handlers) and send it some necessary data. A previous approach was to do a URI::get() call, but that doesn't receive the variables I need it to, hence this search for a solution. Any ideas? (see the referenced question).

Comment: @insaner If you're running another script you can pass it data in the environment, on the commandline, or through the filesystem. Same rules apply as would without CGI.

Comment: sorry, I should have clarified (this is mentioned in the other question), the reason it used a get() call and the reason why I would need the data in $r is because I need to know how apache would resolve certain rewrite rules and redirects, so it's not as easy as just calling a script modifying the ENV (which I have done in other scripts before). In other words, a get("/path/something") could resolve to a script but it could also resolve to just an index.html. In such a case it would make no sense to call the index.html as a script. I would also need to make the same request type (GET or POST)

Comment: @insaner Okay, well the answer is no, you can't do that. A CGI doesn't have a hook into the Apache API, a new GET isn't the same thing as a subrequest, and you don't have access to anything like notes. If you want to hit a public HTTP endpoint you have to play by the same rules as any one else who can access that endpoint.

Comment: @insaner the only backchannel you could conceivably use, IMO, is the filesystem.

Comment: ok, thanks for the input anyways, I'll see if some lateral thinking can yield a possible approach for this and post whatever findings I come across. Thanks again.